# Transformer Neural Network architecture question - query, key and value matrices

Tags: matrix, neural-network, transformer-model

please help me to understand query, key and value matrices in transformer architecture. How many query, key and value matrices should be in one encoder? For example I have only one head of attention and ten embeddings, does it mean that it should be only one set of the matrices (saying "set" I mean three matrices - query, key and value matrix), or it means that each of ten embedding shoud have its own set of the matrices?

I tried to create encoder on "processing" programming language with one set of the matrices, the results of the output are strange (looks like the resulting vectors are almost identical, but they should be different), so I came here to clarify the theory, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to attempt to answer your question, it seems imprecise on many levels.

Single one-head self-attention layer will have a single Key, single Value, single Query matrix.

These matrices will be created in the same way, have the same dimensions, they will be multiplied by an input in the same way, but the resulting tensors will be used in a different way when computing final attention score.:
[image: attention formula]

Can you elaborate what do you mean by "Ten embeddings"?  10 can refer to different things, for example:

- batch_size
- your vocabulary size (number of all possible tokens, i.e letters or words, or sub-words)
- number of outputs from the embedding layer
- number of tokens in the sequence (sentence) you are inputting to the network (or generating with the network, depending on the task you are trying to solve)

Comment: By "ten embeddings" I mean for example ten words as an input. Thanks for the explanation.